# why does android native apps have back navigation button

Tags: android

I found this in android docs. However, I also find that android native apps provide back buttons in their apps.

> Back navigation is how users move backward through the history of
>   screens they previously visited. All Android devices provide a Back
>   button for this type of navigation, **so your app should not add a Back**
>   **button to the UI.**

Could please provide why is android providing back buttons in their apps?

I had back buttons on my activities which I removed after reading the docs.

Comment: Maybe you're conflating it with the ["up navigation" pattern](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)?

Comment: oops...thanks for the pointers.